# For people who work in microbiology labs, what software do you use to manage your strains?

Tags: microbiology, lab-techniques, software

It's just a small microbiology lab that currently records everything on paper, and there's quite few mutants as well. Is Excel commonly used for this sort of thing? Or is there a better software to manage a lab?

Thanks for any help

Comment: check out benchling for constructs... is that the sort of software you mean?

Comment: @shigeta not exactly, although this is pretty cool. But we're just looking for something offline, to keep track of all the different strains in a fridge, and when they mutate to somehow show that the mutants are related

Comment: What I think you're looking for is normally called an LIMS (Laboratory Inventory Management System), and I've never used a good one.  Seriously, decided to spend the effort to build one in house because everything else we tried was horrible.

Comment: That's why most people who can afford it write their own LIMS systems - few labs ever do things the same to use a 'generic' LIMS.

Comment: @AtlLED Thanks, and yeah I've been looking around for the past couple days and it seems like most free LIMS are pretty terrible. And when you say you built one, did you end up designing it with SQL? Or did you use an Access database (or something like that)?

Comment: In my old lab we started with a .Net solution and then moved to an SQL/web based one. Now my lab uses a very similar modification of the SQL one. I want to add that my experience with LIMS that you pay for "semi-out-of-the-box", ie Nautilus, are also crap.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for [StrainControl Laboratory Manager.](http://www.straincontrol.com) Works perfect and covers all needs of a lab. Do not go for all the "free" stuff since they rely on a active sponsor and your data is never safe.

StrainControl is free for 3 months and if you want to continue use it you simply purchase the Admin password and all your data is saved.